# sklearn, xgboost ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn, xgboost

```
pip install -q hvplot
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from scipy import stats 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import hvplot.pandas

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

from sklearn.metrics import (
    accuracy_score, confusion_matrix, classification_report, 
    roc_auc_score, roc_curve, auc,
    plot_confusion_matrix, plot_roc_curve
)

from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, BatchNormalization 
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import AUC

pd.set_option('display.float', '{:.2f}'.format)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 50)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 50)
```

I'm trying to run a code from Kaggle.
https://www.kaggle.com/code/faressayah/lending-club-loan-defaulters-prediction

However, I was stuck in the first few steps, which are the code lines above.  I've spent hours on this and can't figure it out. I got the following error message

[image: error message]

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you very much for helping out!

Comment: Have you installed xgboost?

Comment: Agreed with @ForceBru. You'll likely need to explicitly pip install xgboost.